# ¿En que parte de este codigo construye la ventana? Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

estoy viendo el libro "Programming python" de Mark Lutz en el cual hay un ejemplo el 9.27 que muestra como hacer tareas en un metodo de tiempo (after). lo cual funciona genial, pero queria preguntar en la comunidad con respecto al GUI de ese ejemplo, nose en que momento crea la ventana principal (root/raiz/=tk.Tk()) para poder cambiar titulo geometria incluso agregar una imagen con un label adicional
aqui dejo el codigo a ver quien puede responderme.

```
from tkinter import *
class Alarm(Frame):
    def __init__(self, msecs=1000): # default = 1 second
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.msecs = msecs
        self.pack()
        stopper = Button(self, text='Stop the beeps!', command=self.quit)
        stopper.pack()
        stopper.config(bg='navy', fg='white', bd=8)
        self.stopper = stopper
        self.repeater()
    def repeater(self): # on every N millisecs
        self.bell() # beep now
        self.stopper.flash() # flash button now
        self.after(self.msecs, self.repeater) # reschedule handler
if __name__ == '__main__': Alarm(msecs=1000).mainloop()
```

Comment: Natan, había empezado a editar tu pregunta con la intención de marcar el código para que aparezca como tal, cuando vi que está todo mal indentado, y con las líneas sin separar correctamente, de modo que mejor lo arreglas tú. Mira aquí cómo hacerlo: ---> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Gracias! muy importante aporte ya lo corregì

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando en tu  método `__init__()` de tu clase `Alarm` invocas el constructor del `Frame`, con `Frame.__init__(self)` no le estás pasando como parámetro cuál es el "padre" de este Frame, de modo que en ese momento su constructor crea la ventana raiz para que ese Frame tenga un padre.

Ya que es el constructor del `Frame` quien lo hace, no tienes oportunidad de cambiarle el título o la geometría. Para evitarlo tienes que:

- Crear tú mismo la ventana raíz con `root = Tk()`
- Configurarla a tu gusto
- Pasarla como parámetro al constructor de `Alarm`, para que éste a su vez la pueda pasar como parámetro al constructor de `Frame`. Es decir:

```
from tkinter import *
class Alarm(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, msecs=1000): # default = 1 second
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # Aqui se la pasamos a Frame
        self.msecs = msecs
        self.pack()
        stopper = Button(self, text='Stop the beeps!', command=self.quit)
        stopper.pack()
        stopper.config(bg='navy', fg='white', bd=8)
        self.stopper = stopper
        self.repeater()

    def repeater(self): # on every N millisecs
        self.bell() # beep now
        self.stopper.flash() # flash button now
        self.after(self.msecs, self.repeater) # reschedule handler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Aqui la creamos y configuramos
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Mi titulo")
    root.geometry("300x200")
    # Y se la pasamos al constructor de Alarm
    Alarm(parent=root, msecs=1000)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta Estimado, fuiste muy claro y preciso.
disculpa los adminisrtadores si en el hilo no se permite agradecer! pero muchas gracias, estoy empezando en python y quiero aprender mucho porque veo hya muchas prestaciones comunidad y bibliografia.

Comment: @NatanJimenez No hay de qué. La forma "oficial" de agradecer consiste en votar positivamente la respuesta y/o marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: LO hice al tiro!

Comment: Una consulta mas! del mismo codigo
el boton "Stopper" esta creado en el constructor frame quisiera pasarlo  al root pero creo que al llamarlo en el metodo repeater genera un error por que la instancia estaria mal creada ¿còmo debo hacerlo? ¿Debo eliminarlo por completo del contructor?